# How to manually trigger activation of a viewmodel in Durandal?

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

Durandal docs are sparse on using the activator. I am trying to manually trigger the activation of a `nav` viewmodel from `home` viewmodel. How do I do that?

shell.html

```
<section>
  <!-- ko compose: {model: nav} --><!-- /ko -->

  <section data-bind="router: {cacheViews: true}"></section>
</section>
```

home.js

```
define(function (require) {
   var nav = require('viewmodels/nav'),
   activate = function() {
      //how to activate nav manually here?
      //I am looking for something like:

      //return activator.activate(nav);

      //that would fire the transition of the *nav* module and would allow me to reuse
      //the transition promise and delay activation of *home* module
   };

   return {activate: activate, nav: nav};

});
```

nav.js

```
define(function (require) {
   var activate = function() {
       //is this the correct way to disable auto-activation 
       //of viewmodel during composition?
      return false;
   };

   return {activate: activate};

});
```

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: As far as my knowledge is concerned, calling activator manually should solve your problem!

Comment: The use case is to show \ hide modules that are not tied to router. Currently I am using visible binding, but that does not allow me to use transition logic. So, in this particular example, the use case would be to delay transition of the *route* module until the *nav* module has transitioned.

Comment: @RahulPatil that's what I am after! Please, answer with an example of calling activator manually

Comment: I've update my question to explain the use case better

Comment: Are you simply trying to compose the nav view within the home page? If so, have you tried using `<div data-bind="compose:'viewmodels/nav'"></div>` or `<!--ko compose: 'viewmodels/nav'-->`?

Comment: Also, returning false from the `activate` method means that the view will not activate, compose, or bind. So, you want to include some conditional logic there that returns `true`; otherwise, what's the point?